# Make A Child Div Full Window Width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to force a div to full window width despite of it's parent(s) width. All the methods I am trying making the the div full width but from parent divs' left starting point. Here is the HTML:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  var winWidth = $(window).width();

  $('.expand').css({
    'width': winWidth,
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('expand').css({
      'width': winWidth,
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background:#fff;
}
.page {
  width:70%;
  margin:100px auto;
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:10px;
}
.expand {
  padding:50px;
  text-align:center;
  background:green;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="expand">
        Content...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How do I expand the width of the child div regardless of the width of the parent elements?

Comment: Why not use `.expand { width: 100vw }` ?

Comment: looks like you need `fixed` position?

Comment: What is wrong with your implementation? seems working fine..

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.expand {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

or

```
.expand {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position absolute:

```css
body{
  background:#fff;
  position:relative;
 }
.page{
  width:70%;
  margin:100px auto;
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:10px;
}
.expand{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding:50px;
  text-align:center;
  background:green;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div class="page">
  <div class="content">
   <div class="expand">
    Content...
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```